# How do I run PHP Unit Tests w/ XDEBUG from within PHPStorm [on Mac]?

Tags: phpunit, xdebug

**My tools:**

- Instance generated with buildkit - civibuild: $ civibuild create
  dmaster --url http://d47.localhost --admin-pass mypass
- Mac OS + PHPStorm 8.0.4 + MAMP (/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/bin/php)

I've been close to getting this to work a number of times - but still coming up short. I've looked at Eileen's: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Tests+in+phpstorm and at Tim's [How can I use Xdebug with CiviCRM unit tests?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15896/how-can-i-use-xdebug-with-civicrm-unit-tests/15899#15899) - but something is always slightly different.

UPDATE - after buildkit and phpstorm updates -> I’ve posted new slides in the answer below!

Comment: For Netbeans users, the [equivalent instructions are available here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/27429/12)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are the steps/complete set of screenshots of a configuration that now works for me:

**1) from command line ensure you can run buildkit -> civibuild**

$ civibuild create dmaster --type drupal-demo --civi-ver master --url http://dmaster.localhost --admin-user myuser --admin-pass mypass

**2) from command line ensure you can run tests** - that all is working properly

karins-macbook-pro:civicrm sysadmin$ pwd
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buildkit/build/dmaster/sites/all/modules/civicrm

```
$ cd /path/to/civicrm
$ env CIVICRM_UF=UnitTests phpunit4 ./tests/phpunit/CRM/AllTests.php

Installing dmastertes_7by9i schema

Installing dmastertes_7by9i database
PHPUnit 4.8.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

...............................................

.......
^X^C
```

**3) Ensure you can fire up a http://d47.localhost/ in a browser and debug/set breakpoints** anywhere in PHPStorm / step through code in your Drupal/CiviCRM code base - e.g.

[image]

**4. PHPStorm: Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP:**

[image]

**5. PHPStorm: Preferences -> Project: Directories:**

[image]

**6. PHPStorm: Preferences -> Language & Frameworks -> PHP -> PHPUnit:**

[image]

**7. PHPStorm: Run -> Edit Configurations -> Default -> PHP Unit:**

[image]

**8. Run the test by right clicking on the test itself:**

[image]

**9. Et voila:**

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE JULY 2018**
After updating buildkit:

```
cd ~/buildkit
git pull
./bin/civi-download-tools
```

I had to make some edits as some of the paths have changed. The edits I made are:

ad 4:
[image]

ad 5:
[image]

ad 7: note you want to `Include parent environment variables`
[image]

And we're up and running again:
[image]

**UPDATE AUGUST 2020**
After updating buildkit and PHPStorm -> here's the new screenshots!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Running a test via the command line also using phpunit5 now:

```
karins-MBP:civicrm sysadmin$ env CIVICRM_UF=UnitTests phpunit5 --filter testSubmitWithTax ./tests/phpunit/CRM/Member/Form/MembershipRenewalTest
Parsing schema description /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/buildkit/build/dmaster/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/xml/schema/Schema.xml
Extracting database information
Extracting table information
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)
Installing dmastercivi_rb7eb database
Time: 9.92 seconds, Memory: 58.50MB
OK (1 test, 18 assertions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a wild guess - are you setting

```
define('CIVICRM_UF', 'Drupal');
```

somewhere in your civicrm.setting file (I know we do)?

Comment: This is a buildkit - civibuild: $ civibuild create dmaster --url http://d47.localhost --admin-pass mypass

Comment: So this didn't work for me, until I updated the composer version of phpunit shipped with buildkit to 4.8.21 and used that in phpstorm.  Then everything worked beautifully!

Comment: How old is your buildkit? 

Comment: checking versions: karins-macbook-pro:buildkit sysadmin$ phpunit4 --version
PHPUnit 4.8.21 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.