# How do I run CiviCRM PHPUnit tests from within Netbeans?

Tags: developer, unit-testing, phpunit

I want to run PHPUnit tests from within my IDE - and I know Karin G. has created [excellent directions](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/16489/12) for PHPStorm, but I use Netbeans 8.2.  What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This all assumes you have `civicrm-buildkit` already working and that you can run CiviCRM phpunit tests successfully from the command line.]

### 1. Tell Netbeans which phpunit executable you're using.

- Go to **Tools » Options**, then **PHP** tab, **PHPUnit subtab**.
- Set the path of your PHPUnit script.  See screenshot:

[image]

### 2. Create a shell script with your environment variable.

Copy this script into a file anywhere on your filesystem:

```
#!/bin/sh
env CIVICRM_UF=UnitTests /path/to/your/phpunit5 $@
```

### 3. Tell Netbeans where to find your tests.

- Go to **File menu » Project Properties**, **Testing** tab.
- Click **Add Folder** and select the `<civiroot>/tests/phpunit` folder.  See screenshot:

[image]

### 4. Tell Netbeans the CiviCRM-specific info it needs.

- Go to **File menu » Project Properties**, **PHPUnit** tab.
- Check the **Use XML Configuration** box.
- Set the XML Configuration path to `<civiroot>/phpunit.xml.dist`.
- Check the **Use Custom PHPUnit Script** box.
- Set the **PHPUnit Script** to the path of the file from step 2.

[image]

### 5. You're ready to go!

From any PHP file in the main codebase, press `Ctrl-F6` (or **Run menu » Test File**) to start your tests.  You can also re-run only failed tests.

### Troubleshooting

If PHPUnit isn't working, bring up the "Output" window (**Window menu » Output**).  This will show you the exact command Netbeans tried to run.  You can run it on your command line to compare results and tweak it.

Comment: Following onto this, it's also possible to get breakpoints working with a few tweaks to Jon G's instructions, by specifying an alternate port in Netbeans and in the bash script. See here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/18qsvcwuoga2nGmUVd__l8TcqaMO368PTrsgJfpESpl8/edit#heading=h.b5svm5gmgfpq