# How do I run PHP Unit test on civicrm-buildkit-vagrant from within PHPStorm?

Tags: cv

I don't understand why PHPStorm does not see `cv` tool when I call "run" or "debug" the class from extension:

**cv: not found PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Command failed (cv php:boot --level=classloader)**

I can use `cv` tool when I'm on vagrant machine (vagrant up, vagrant ssh, cv --version)

However I can run the test directly from vagrant machine. I also can debug any civicrm form called by browser (remote debugging).

My setup:

- civicrm-buildkit-vagrant on virtualbox
- cv version v0.1.29
- PHP7.1 + PHPUnit 4.8.36 + xdebug 2.6.0
- PHPStorm 2018.1
- runner is configured for extension (configuration and bootstrap file)

**Languages & Frameworks > PHP:**

[image]

**Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Test Frameworks:**

[image]

**Remote CLI Interpreters:**

[image]

> ```
> vagrant:///home/tomasz/cividev/usr/bin/php7.1 /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --bootstrap
> ```
>
> /srv/www/wemove/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/eu.wemove.gidipirus/tests/phpunit/bootstrap.php
>   --configuration /srv/www/wemove/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/eu.wemove.gidipirus/phpunit.xml.dist
>   CRM_Gidipirus_BaseTest
>   /srv/www/wemove/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/eu.wemove.gidipirus/tests/phpunit/CRM/Gidipirus/BaseTest.php
>       sh: 1: cv: not found
>       PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Command failed (cv php:boot --level=classloader):
>        in /srv/www/wemove/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/eu.wemove.gidipirus/tests/phpunit/bootstrap.php:31
>       Stack trace:
>       #0 /srv/www/wemove/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/eu.wemove.gidipirus/tests/phpunit/bootstrap.php(6):
>   cv('cv php:boot --l...', 'phpcode')
>       #1 phar:///srv/config/phpunit-4.8.36.phar/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php(56):
>   include_once('/srv/www/wemove...')
>       #2 phar:///srv/config/phpunit-4.8.36.phar/phpunit/Util/Fileloader.php(38):
>   PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load('/srv/www/wemove...')
>       #3 phar:///srv/config/phpunit-4.8.36.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(779):
>   PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad('/srv/www/wemove...')
>       #4 phar:///srv/config/phpunit-4.8.36.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(596):
>   PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleBootstrap('/srv/www/wemove...')
>       #5 /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php(304): PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments(Array)
>       #6 phar:///srv/config/phpunit-4.8.36.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php(111):
>   IDE_Base in
>   /srv/www/wemove/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/eu.wemove.gidipirus/tests/phpunit/bootstrap.php
>   on line 31
>
> ```
> Process finished with exit code 255
> ```

I know there is a [How do I run PHP Unit Tests w/ XDEBUG from within PHPStorm [on Mac]?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16489/how-do-i-run-php-unit-tests-w-xdebug-from-within-phpstorm-on-mac) question but there is a standard installation of civicrm by buildkit, not by whole vagrant script.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.